# Is it possible to add filters when performing a GET elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a situation where I want to filter the results not when performing a search but rather a GET using elasticsearch. Basically I have a Document that has a status field indicating that the entity has a state of discarded. When performing the GET I need to check the value of this field thereby excluding it if the status is indeed one of "discarded".

I know i can do this using a search with a term query, but what about when using a GET against the index based on Document ID?

Update: Upon further investigation, it seems the only way to do this is to use percolation or a search. I hope I am wrong if anyone has any suggestions I am all ears.

Just to clarify I am using the Java API.

thanks

Comment: Why not just do a term search on `_id` with the filter?

Comment: True, I was thinking a GET would be faster than a search. A wrong assumption it seems.

Comment: Yeah, it might be, but by how much is the question I guess. Have you benchmarked it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
curl http://domain/my_index/_search -d '{
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "ids" : {
          "type" : "my_type",
          "values" : ["123"]
        }
      },
      {
        "term" : {
          "discarded" : "false"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

NOTE: you can also use a missing filter if the discarded field does not exist on some docs.

NOTE 2: I don't think this will be markedly slower than a normal get request either...

Comment: Ah forgot about the `ids` filter +1